# CSS Positioning with nested fixed property

Tags: html, css

```css
.a{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  z-index:1000000

}

.b{
  position:fixed;
  color:green;
  background:pink;
  left:60px;

}

.c{
  position:relative;
 
}

.d{
  position:static;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

  <div class="b">
  c is overlapping d is not
  </div>
  <span class="c">
overlaping sibling
  </span>
  <span class="d">
  i    am    not a overlapping     sibling
</span>
</div>
```

[Click here for JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41p3u7qL/4/)
In the above fiddle i have an html please go through it an explain me why 
`<span class="c">` is overlapping on the `<div class = "b">` and why `<span class="d">` is not overlapping on the `<div class = "b">`
what is difference between these two spans why is behaving differently?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1):

because `<span class="d">` has `position:static`. you can ref below link if you want to learn more. thanks

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: i agree but i want to know the reason why one span is going behind and one span element is on the top